# The difference between todoudle and double.parse

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to Know the difference between `todoudle` and `double.parse` in dart and where are each of them used?

The result of both is the same, but the difference may be in the compilation

Comment: one is more like object oriented and another one is more like functional.

Comment: [`num.toDouble`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/num/toDouble.html) is used to convert an existing number to a `double`. [`double.parse`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/double/parse.html) is used to convert a `String` to a `double`.  They are not interchangeable at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**double.parse** is used to convert a string to a double.
Example:

```
String value= "3.54";
double newValue= double.parse(value);
```

**toDouble** is used to convert a numeric value of another data type to a double.

```
int value= 3;
double newValue= value.toDouble();
```

Answer (score -2):

You can only use toDouble function when type of variable is int, double or num. If you have dynamic variable, you don't know exactly type, you want to convert to double, you can use double.parse() or double.tryParse()

Comment: `double.parse`/`double.tryParse` can be used only on `String`s.

Comment: yup, you can use toString function, right